# Convert to GMT time without changing date

Tags: r

I query a data base and get back a vector of dates in EST time

```
d =as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-19 00:38:08 EST","2015-06-19 00:38:33 EST"))
d
```

Here the vector

```
d
[1] "2015-06-19 00:38:08 EST" "2015-06-19 00:38:33 EST"
```

BUT I want the timezone to be in GMT time.

How can I get results that look like

```
d
[1] "2015-06-19 00:38:08 GMT" "2015-06-19 00:38:33 GMT"
```

Comment: Anything you've already tried?

Comment: `as.POSIXlt(d,tz="GMT")` gives `"2015-06-19 00:38:08 GMT"`

Comment: When I run that it changes the time

Comment: Changes the time for me too.

Comment: Don't do the first `as.POSIXlt`, i.e. `d = c(bla blah)` or convert `d` to `character` in the second posixt if first is necessary, as @jlhoward suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to have an unambiguous way of making a time in US New York time (for which EST" is also ambiguous owing to the existence of an Eastern time zone in Australia as well. Better would be EST5EDT or "America/New_York".) If you run the code you used in a different time zone you don't get the same time:

```
> d =as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-19 00:38:08 EST","2015-06-19 00:38:33 EST"))
> d
[1] "2015-06-19 00:38:08 PDT" "2015-06-19 00:38:33 PDT"
```

The time zone portion of character times is basically ignored at the time of creation by as.POSIXct. Instead use:

```
> d =as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-19 00:38:08 EST","2015-06-19 00:38:33 EST"), tz="America/New_York", usetz=TRUE)
> d
[1] "2015-06-19 00:38:08 EDT" "2015-06-19 00:38:33 EDT"
```

Notice that the correct display of the Daylight Savings time has been displayed. Then you can use `format.POSIXt` for output of "the same time" in the GMT/UCT/UTC timezone:

```
> format(d, tz="GMT")
[1] "2015-06-19 04:38:08" "2015-06-19 04:38:33"
```

I hope this is a fair summary of how `strptime` handles datetime input:

> Date-times are implicitly entered in the current timezone set by locale setting with any trailing `tz` indicator ignored with no warning and stored as UCT with an offset determined by the locale's difference from UCT. The timezone formatting %-'specials' are only used on output with `strftime` and `format.POSIXt`.

Answer (score 3):

Like this? I'm not exactly sure what your trying to accomplish. The title of your question asks to "change the time w/o changing the date" but your example changes nothing but the timezone. This produces the result in your example.

```
d <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-19 00:38:08 EST","2015-06-19 00:38:33 EST"))
d
# [1] "2015-06-19 00:38:08 EDT" "2015-06-19 00:38:33 EDT"
as.POSIXct(as.character(d),tz="GMT")
# [1] "2015-06-19 00:38:08 GMT" "2015-06-19 00:38:33 GMT"
```

Comment: To my reading of the question, this would result in a "different time", although I admit the phrase is ambiguous.

Comment: @BondedDust I agree. But if you compare OP's inputs (first line of the question) to the desired output (last line), all that has changed is the tz. Yes absolutely these are different times.

Comment: I think we basically agree. It's very possible your answer was what was desired. With an international banking system that runs on "real-time", I think it's important to understand that it very easy to get the misleading results with R's date-time system. The design of the date-time objects uses UCT under the hood, but the data input can be very confusing.

Comment: It's also possible that the data is in GMT but without tz set explicitly, and the way OP imports sets a local-specific tz. This is how `quantmod::getSymbols(...)` works, for instance.